# Converting class component with state to functional component with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm have difficulties to convert a class component to functional. I have watched multiple examples for doing this task, but still I know the basics. How can I change my code to be a functional component with using useState and useEffect hooks and maybe if someone has some resources where I can find the best practices on this topic? Here is the example of the code that I'm trying to convert:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { storeProducts, detailProduct } from "./data";

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
//Provider
//Consumer

class ProductProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        products: [],
        detailProduct: detailProduct
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setProducts();
    }

    setProducts = () => {
        let tempProducts = [];
        storeProducts.forEach(item => {
            const singleItem = {...item};
            tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
        })
        this.setState(() => {
            return {products: tempProducts }
        });
    };

    handleDetail = () => {
        console.log("hello from detail");
    };

    addToCart = () => {
        console.log("hello from addToCart");
    };
render() {
    return (
            <ProductContext.Provider value={{
                ...this.state,
                handleDetail: this.handleDetail,
                addToCart: this.addToCart
            }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `useContext` in functional components to get the context.

```
const ctx = React.createContext();

function ProductProvider(props) {
  const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
  const [detailProduct, setDetailProduct] = React.useState(detailProduct);
  const ProductContext = React.useContext(ctx);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    handleProducts();
  }, []);

  function handleProducts() {
    let tempProducts = [];
    storeProducts.forEach(item => {
      const singleItem = { ...item };
      tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
    });

    setProducts(tempProducts);

    // it could simple be written as
    setProducts(storeProducts);
  }

  function handleDetail() {
    console.log("hello from detail");
  }

  function addToCart() {
    console.log("hello from addToCart");
  }

  return (
    <ProductContext.Provider
      value={{
        products,
        detailProduct,
        handleDetail,
        addToCart
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ProductContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried @Prateek Thapa code, but it is showing me the error that ProviderContext is not defined. The error is showing because after my function I have a constant: 
 **const ProductCounsumer = ProductContext.Consumer**
 which is not in the function. 
 Also I changed my const name in my data.js to 'detailedProduct' because it has the same name as the const in the useEffect line. So after these changes I have this example with no errors, but still I am not sure if this work like it should be. Can this work without useContext if I have this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { storeProducts, detailedProduct } from "./data";

const ProductContext = React.createContext();
//Provider
//Consumer

function ProductProvider(props) {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [detailProduct, setDetailProduct] = useState(detailedProduct);

    useEffect(() => {
      handleProducts();
    }, []);

    function handleProducts() {
      let tempProducts = [];
      storeProducts.forEach(item => {
        const singleItem = { ...item };
        tempProducts = [...tempProducts, singleItem];
      });

      setProducts(tempProducts);

      setProducts(storeProducts);
    }

    function handleDetail() {
      console.log("hello from detail");
    }

    function addToCart() {
      console.log("hello from addToCart");
    }

    return (
      <ProductContext.Provider
        value={{
          products,
          detailProduct,
          handleDetail,
          addToCart
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </ProductContext.Provider>
    );
  }
const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer };
```

Comment: See again, you're missing `useContext` inside your function.